# Com identificar se o acesso é interno ou externo?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma aplicação em asp.mvc que possui 3 (três) tipos de acesso, 2 interno e 1 externo.
Acesso interno é feito pelo LDAP e o externo por uma tabela de usuario.

```
No entanto o usuário externo também pode está na rede interna.(aqui é a xarada)
```

Como identificar esse acesso? Pois a aplicação consome serviços internos que usam IP diferentes para acesso externo. Daí preciso saber qual é o tipo de acesso para colocar o IP certo para o consumo do serviço.

Ex:

```
usuario de acesso interno com DAP quer consultar um pdf (ipInterno:56644/consulta)
```

Outro acesso, mas é o mesmo IP do serviço, pois está na rede interna

```
Usuario de acesso externo mas na rede interna quer consultar um pdf (ipInterno:56644/consulta)
```

Outro

```
Usuario de acesso externo fora da rede interna quer consultar um pdf (ipExterno:56344/consulta)
```

Comment: Não tem autenticação na rede interna?

Comment: não tem........

Comment: o IP de dentro da corporação é fixo?

Comment: sim............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que o IP da sua empresa é fixo, você pode verificar dessa forma, faz a checagem do IP, se for o corporativo faz uma chamada, se não for, faz outra chamada.

A baixo segue duas formas de verificar o IP externo

Primeiro pelo `WebClient` consumindo serviço de terceiros

```
string meuIpExternoDownload = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");

Console.WriteLine($"Meu IP por download: {meuIpExternoDownload}");
```

O segundo seria baixando a biblioteca `IpPublicKnowledge` pelo `nuget` - (`Install-Package IpPublicKnowledge`)

```
var ip = IPK.GetMyPublicIp();
var IPinfo = IPK.GetIpInfo(ip);

Console.WriteLine($"Meu IP por IpPublicKnowledge: {IPinfo.IP}");
```

Dica: Se optar por fazer dessa forma, salve o IP Externo em algum arquivo de configuração(`web.config`), assim se o IP fixo, por algum motivo mudar, você irá precisar alterar apenas lá.

Comment: vou adaptar ao meu código, se funcionar eu marco a resposta. Obrigada desde ja

Comment: esse serviço me retorna 189.16.19.50 quando na verdade a minha rede começa com 10.21

Comment: Esse IP(10.21) é da sua maquina  e é interno, o que começa com 189[...] é o IP externo, de uma olhada aqui [O que é IP](https://www.infowester.com/ip.php). Pelo IP interno não é seguro fazer essa verificação, pois o IP interno pode ser o mesmo no computador de casa quanto no do trabalho. Nesse [site](http://www.meuip.com.br/) você consegue ver seu IP externo.

Comment: O Intiuto é saber se o acesso vem de fora da empresa ou de dentro. Por esse retorno, eu sempre vou ter o acesso setado pra externo quando na verdade eu estou acessando de dentro da rede da empresa.

Comment: Se o seu sistema estiver publicado na internet sempre terá um IP externo acessando ele. Seja o da casa de um funcionário ou o da empresa. Se o IP da sua empresa for fixo você consegue ver se ele está acessando de dentro da empresa ou de fora. Porque no caso de um acesso de fora da empresa o IP Externo será outro. Porém, o IP externo da empresa teria que ser fixo.

Comment: o Ip da empresa é fixo... Seria justamente isso que preciso. Ver se ele acessa de dentro da empresa ou de fora.

Comment: Então, o IP 189[...] que retornou é o IP externo fixo da sua empresa. Exemplo, no momento meu IP interno é 10.20[...], já o externo é 200.155[...], no meu caso eu faria `if(meuIpExterno == '200.155[...]') //Faz alguma coisa `

Comment: Se desejar, podemos mover essa conversa para o chat, lá posso tentar explicar melhor..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77483/discussion-between-danielle-arruda-torres-and-barbetta).